# Javascript file not loading properly in FIrefox with no extra information

Tags: typescript, firefox

I was trying to use import in my Typescript code but on opneing in firefox I get the error

"Loading failed for the module with source flashcard"

My impport in my fie looks like this

```js
import Flashcard from "./flashcard"
```

And the flashcard file looks like this

```
export default class FlashCard {
    front: string;
    back: string;
    
    constructor(front:string, back:string)
    {
        this.front = front;
        this.back = back;
    }
}
```

I have looked under netwoek but it is entirly empty

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Needed to add .js to the file in import

```js
import Flashcard from "./flashcard.js"
```